# How to print a webpage twice on the same A4 Sheet?

Tags: html, css, web, media-queries

I want two printed copies of the invoice on the same A4 sheet. Is there anyway to achieve the same? It is guaranteed that the single print of the invoice(aka html table in my case), will not exceed more than half of the A4 sheet.

Comment: How does your '@media print'  code look like?

Comment: I haven't used it as of now!

Comment: @Mugé, do you have any solution to my problem?

Comment: Make use of B5 page size print, if data exceeds than the B5 it will be still on the same page else you will be getting 2 copies of invoice on the same A4.

Comment: @taurus05 I just posted below.  Although the 2 invoice tables look close to each other, once you prepare your invoice template that fits into half of an A4 page, it should hopefully work.  You can also adjust the margins. The code looks right to me, but I haven't prepared an invoice format.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question correctly, your .html file that will print out 2 invoices on an A4 page will first need to be prepared as an .html/.php file ( webpage ) and then printed.
I will also assume, you have created a dynamic page that pulls the data into the invoice.

```css
/** style.css  **/

.invoice {
  margin-top: 2em;
}

span {
  color: blue;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.extra span {
  color: inherit;
}

@media print {
    body{
        width: 21cm;
        height: 29.7cm;
        margin: 20mm; /* Adjust margin as you like. */        
   } 
   
   * {background: transparent !important; color: black !important; text-shadow: none !important; filter:none !important; -ms-filter: none !important} /* Black prints faster */
   
   pre, blockquote {border: 1px solid #999; page-break-inside: avoid; }


thead {display: table-header-group; } /* Repeat header row at top of each printed page */
  tr, img {page-break-inside: avoid; }
  
  img {max-width: 100% !important; }
  
  @page {margin: 0.5cm}
  
  p, h2, h3 {orphans: 3; widows: 3}
  
  h2, h3{page-break-after: avoid}
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

</head>

<body>

<div class="invoice">
  Here is <span>First invoice table format</span>
</div>

<div class="invoice extra" style="color:green">
  Here is <span>Second invoice table format</span>.
</div>

</body>
</html>
```